# Is it possible to modify item in Map without removing?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have `ConcurrentMap<Integer, MyObj>` in my program.
Can I modify `MyObj` if I know a key? Without deleting and putting a new `MyObj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only that, but if you keep the original reference to the object, you can still modify it.

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
myMap.put("key", o);

o.setName("foo");
myMap.get("key").getName(); //will return "foo"
myMap.get("key").setName("bar");
myMap.get("key").getName(); //will return "bar"

o = null; //this applies only for your local reference, not for the map
myMap.get("key").getName(); //will STILL return "bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your definition of "modify." If you want to mutate something internal to `MyObj`, and that object is mutable, you certainly can do this.

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, MyObj> map = /* snip */;
map.get(someKey).callMutatorMethod();
```

If you want to replace the object with an entirely new instance, you can just call `Map#put()`, which will overwrite the existing mapped value, if such a value exists.

Comment: If you have a reference to `MyObj`, nothing prevents you from mutating its state. `ConcurrentMap` only ensures modifications to the map itself (puts, deletes, etc.) don't muck with modifications in other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The map simply holds a reference to the object. The object can change without having to update the map.

```
Map<Integer, MyObj> myMap = new ConcurrentMap<Integer, MyObj>();
myMap.put(1, new MyObj());
MyObj obj = myMap.get(1);
obj.setFoo("Foo");
```